# Question about what changed from flutter 1.0 to 2.0

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout, flutter-test

This error occurred while using the example code of flutter 1.0

```
    Widget _buildBody(BuildContext context) {
    return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
      stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('member').snapshots(),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return LinearProgressIndicator();
        return _buildList(context, snapshot.data.docs);
      },
    );
  }



  Widget _buildList(BuildContext context, List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
    List<DocumentSnapshot> searchResults = [];
    for (DocumentSnapshot d in snapshot) {
      if (d.data.toString().contains(_searchText)) {
        searchResults.add(d);
      }
    }
    return Expanded(
      child: GridView.count(
          crossAxisCount: 3,
          childAspectRatio: 1 / 1.5,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(3),
          children: searchResults
              .map((data) => _buildListItem(context, data))
              .toList()),
    );
  }
```

An error occurred in `docs`

`The property 'docs' can't be unconditionally accessed because the receiver can be 'null'. Try making the access conditional (using '?.') or adding a null check to the target ('!').`

Comment: You can read the official announcement for flutter 2, [What’s New in Flutter 2](https://medium.com/flutter/whats-new-in-flutter-2-0-fe8e95ecc65). The error you are having is related to the changes to null safety that were introduced in dart 2.12, see [Announcing Dart 2.12](https://medium.com/dartlang/announcing-dart-2-12-499a6e689c87), and also related guides on the dart website [Understanding null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety) [Migrating to null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/migration-guide) [Null safety codelab](https://dart.dev/codelabs/null-safety)

Comment: If you are still learning and cannot figure out on your own what has changed between two major versions of a product, you are in no position to use a turorial from 2 major versions ago (we are on 3 now). Please start out with tutorials that are recent that can teach you. Then, after you know enough about Dart, you may be able to use the old ones and convert them yourself.